# Two ways of chaining ajax jquery calls. Right one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise, chain

I have the next chain of ajax calls:

```
ajaxCall1().then(function(){
    ajaxCall2(). then(function(){
       ajaxCall3().then(function(){
            ....
        })
    })
 })
```

As you can see I am not returning the ajax calls but its just work fine. The next way is what I have seen as examples:

```
 ajaxCall1()
   .then(function(){
        return ajaxCall2()
    })
   .then(function(){
        return ajaxCall3()
    }).then(function(){
        ....
    })
```

What would be the right way?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first pattern is actually a [well-known promise anti-pattern](http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/).

The chainability of promises allows us to get away from nesting callbacks and maintain a vertical structure.

Comment: Ok,  but the first way I can make sure that ajax calls are not executing at the same time, right? Although according to the pattern is bad style

Comment: The second way and the first way are both sequentially executing your ajax functions.

Answer (score 3):

The second one. In the first one you do not create a promise chain. The first one should look that way:

```
ajaxCall1().then(function() {
  return ajaxCall2().then(function() {
    return ajaxCall3().then(function() {
      .....
    })
  })
})
```

But even then you have the deep nesting which is in general a bad coding style.

If you want to execute the requests in parallel, those requests do not depend on each other and the order in which they are done does not matter you could write:

```
Promise.all([
    ajaxCall1(),
    ajaxCall2(),
    ajaxCall3()
  ])
  .then(results => {

  })
```

If the order matters then use your second approach.

Comment: How to write the first way if sometimes you return an ajax call or sometimes not because its not needed?

Comment: @user3254515 I don not exactly understand what you are asking.

Comment: I mean, how to break the chain of ajax calls if the response of one ajax call is an error?

Comment: @user3254515 If you use your second approach then the chain will automatically  break. So if `ajaxCall1` fails then `ajaxCall2` and `ajaxCall3` won't be executed. If `ajaxCall2` fails, then `ajaxCall3` won't be executed.

Comment: I mean not exactly an ajax error, just evaluate something on the response and break the chain

Comment: @user3254515 There is no general solution for this case. If the reason for the break is something like a not matching condition that can be expressed as an `Error` then you could throw an error, but you should only do that if it is really an Error. Otherwise the strategy heavily depends on the exact use case.